# Convert SQL script to Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know there are difference in access and sql. And I’m trying to convert this script over to Access but am having trouble getting it to work.

```
SELECT TOP 20 g.Title, COALESCE(m1.Pageviews, 0) + COALESCE(m2.Pageviews, 0) + COALESCE(m3.Pageviews,0) AS Total_Pageviews,
COALESCE(m1.Pageviews, 0) AS Month1,
COALESCE(m2.Pageviews, 0) AS Month2,
 COALESCE(m3.Pageviews, 0) AS Month3
FROM (SELECT URL, Title FROM dbo_vw_GoodURLs WHERE URL LIKE '/blog*') g
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_analytics_history m1
ON g.URL = m1.URL AND m1.URL LIKE '/blog*' AND m1.Report_Month = 10
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_analytics_history m2
ON g.URL = m2.URL AND m2.URL LIKE '/blog*' AND m2.Report_Month = 11
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_analytics_history m3
ON g.URL = m3.URL AND m3.URL LIKE '/blog*' AND m3.Report_Month = 12
GROUP BY g.Title, m1.Pageviews, m2.Pageviews, m3.Pageviews
ORDER BY COALESCE(m1.Pageviews, 0) + COALESCE(m2.Pageviews, 0) + COALESCE(m3.Pageviews, 0) DESC;
```

Comment: *I know there are difference in access and sql.* ... MS Access *is* a database than runs SQL. So this is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

In `MS-Acess` you need parenthesis to evaluate multiple `JOIN`s :

```
SELECT TOP 20 g.Title, 
       IIF(m1.Pageviews IS NULL, 0, m1.Pageviews) +
       IIF(m2.Pageviews IS NULL, 0, m2.Pageviews) +
       IIF(m3.Pageviews IS NULL, 0, m3.Pageviews) AS Total_Pageviews,
       . . . 
FROM ((SELECT URL, Title 
       FROM dbo_vw_GoodURLs AS vw LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       dbo_analytics_history m1 
       ON g.URL = m1.URL AND m1.URL LIKE '%blog%' AND m1.Report_Month = 10
       ) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_analytics_history AS m2
         ON g.URL = m2.URL AND m2.URL LIKE '%blog%' AND m2.Report_Month = 11
      ) LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo_analytics_history m3
        ON g.URL = m3.URL AND m3.URL LIKE '/blog*' AND m3.Report_Month = 12
WHERE vw.URL LIKE '%blog%' 
GROUP BY . . . ;
```